# How can I get user information from a JWT token in ASP.NET Core 8?

Tags: encryption, jwt, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-8

I'm writing a client-server application with JWT authorization in ASP.NET Core 8.

Authorization API endpoints are implemented using the `AddIdentityApi` extension method added in .NET 8.

The problem is this: I need to get user information from the JWT token body in my SPA application, but the endpoints added by `AddIdentityApi` are return a responses with encrypted(compressed?) tokens - these tokens do not have dots as a delimiter.

Login response example:

```
{
  "tokenType": "Bearer",
  "accessToken": "CfDJ8GwmsrOCkNBF ... ",    <-- long string without dots
  "expiresIn": 3600,
  "refreshToken": "..."
}
```

Previously I used JWT tokens in ASP.NET and they were readable.

I couldn't find the layer in the authentication system that does this encryption and I don't understand why it is encrypted. The `HttpContext.User` of authorized requests contains all the information I need.

My `Program.cs`:

```
using ICollector.Server.Data;
using ICollector.Server.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("mssql")
        ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string not found.")));

builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<AppUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapGroup("/api/identity").MapIdentityApi<AppUser>();

app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

app.Run();
```

I read this article by [Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-introducing-the-identity-api-endpoints/) where he described the new functionality, but I did not find any explanation about the token format there.

Digging into the framework code, I found a static class `JwtTokenUtilities`, which has a method `DecompressToken(byte[] tokenBytes, string algorithm)`, from which I can conclude that compression can be performed, but is it done in my configuration and I still don’t understand what the algorithm is.

Comment: Bear in mind that there's no guarantee that the access token is an encrypted JWT that contains the user info.

Comment: @phuzi I thought that all the information in HttpContext.User comes from the request data. Requests authorized by these tokens have all the Claims that should have been included in the token.

Comment: Hi,@Artiom, Access tokens do not have to be in any particular format, and in practice, various OAuth servers have chosen many different formats for their access tokens.there's an article related:https://oauth.net/2/access-tokens/  ,hopes help

Comment: @Artiom It can come from the request data but the access token may be as simple as a session token where the token is looked up against the server-side cache of user session data.

Comment: Hi, @RuikaiFeng! Thanks for the useful link. It says that the access token should not be interpreted by the client and is not intended to transfer information about the user. This is what I wanted to be sure of.